# SignedExtension Transaction Pool Deduplication

Tags: transactions, signed-extensions

How do I remove duplications of transactions from the transaction pool? I noticed some return a tag in a signed SignedExtension [TransactionValidity](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/transaction_validity/struct.ValidTransaction.html) provides field. However, it is not clear to me how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the transaction pool deduplicates the transactions using `provides` tags. Right now, if you `provide` two equal values for different transactions, only one will be admitted to the tx pool and later included in the block.
Let's say you have the following code for validating a transaction:

```rust
ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("MyPallet")
                        .priority(TransactionPriority::MAX)
                        .longevity(10)
                        .propagate(true)
                        .and_provides(value_1)
                        .and_provides(value_2)
                        .build()
```

Now, if you have two transactions with an overlap in **EITHER**  `value_1` or `value_2`, one of the transactions will be dropped. That's how the transaction pool deduplicates transactions.

Answer (score 2):

What's your definition of the duplication.

Here is an [example](https://github.dev/paritytech/substrate/blob/dddfed3d9260cf03244f15ba3db4edf9af7467e9/frame/examples/basic/src/lib.rs#L758-L759).
As you can see there's a matcher to analyze the call struct.

Then you could do something like this:

```rust
Some(Call::set_dummy { maybe_a_hash, .. }) {
    if xxx.contains(maybe_a_hash) {
        return InvalidTransaction::Custom(<Error<T>>::AlreadyExisted.as_u8()).into()
    }
}
```